# Android WindowManager Window does not reposition after keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-service, android-windowmanager, window-managers

A window that is shows on screen

```
public class FlatingViewService extends Service{
      public static WindowManager windowManager;
              ...

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
     ...

    //Floating View Layout
   li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   myView = li.inflate(R.layout.product_response_card, null);

  name =  (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.name);

  editTextName = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    ...

    //Layout Parameters
    ...
   response_card_params.softInputMode =  WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE;
```

When user tries to enter some text into editText, Keyboard appears but on top of editText. So the user can't see anything.

What's the actual problem?

Comment: have you tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest file??

Comment: @Maulik.J I am using WindowManager in a service. There is no Activity attached.

Answer (score 5):

Got the problem solved.

```
//Layout Parameters for Product response card
        layout_params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        layout_params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        layout_params.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN;
```

I was using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, instead of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE`

And WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Answer (score 2):

Starting from API 19 options `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` and `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` [don't affect](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/81479358decb0a2cefbb8245e0f56ed0e966d697/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#3280) windows with types `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and `TYPE_TOAST` ([and TYPE_VOLUME_OVERLAY for API 21 and 22](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ca4d040%5E!/); in API 23 `TYPE_VOLUME_OVERLAY` removed from this list).

Instead of use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` need use `TYPE_PHONE`.